# llvm - write a pass that checks if a function is present in a file

Tags: llvm, llvm-clang, llvm-gcc, llvm-c++-api

What I'm trying to achieve here is simple. I need my pass to go through the functions in a file (and hence, FunctionPass) and check if one of them is the one I'm looking for. I want to achieve this in a clean, simple way.

So far, I'm extracting the following info from the functions in the file I'm running the pass over:

- Name
- Return Type
- Number + type of arguments

I already have this info for the function I'm looking for and I've thought about comparing this info with the one extracted to see if there's a match.

But is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: You can try Module->getFunction(StringRef name) if you have the name of the function in modulePass. ref: http://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1Module.html#a209a615a3a32241323420cca24b5520a

Comment: Seems like a good approach... I'll try it out in a couple of days and update here if I have any success!

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you! You can add your comment as an answer and I'll mark it as correct if you want to.

Comment: Good to hear that, just added the answer mark it as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `Module->getFunction(StringRef name)` if you have the name of the function in modulePass.
see: [llvm::Module Class Reference](http://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1Module.html#a209a615a3a32241323420cca24b5520a)